# Can I make "Go to definition" jump to TypeScript code in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, webstorm

WebStorm has a nice feature for TypeScript:  I can right-click on a function reference in a *.html file, either inside a script tag or inside an event handler for a dom element (e.g. 'onclick'), and when I select Go To Declaration, it gives me the option to select the TypeScript definition, so I can jump straight to the TypeScript code.

I'm trying to do something similar in Visual Studio 2013.  Since Visual Studio doesn't seem to support this out of the box, I tried a hack that I thought might work.  I defined a "link" file, with a "links.ts" file name, which actually contains 100% valid JavaScript, but links to functions defined within other TypeScript files.

I then add a script reference to links.ts in my html page.  The problem is, the "Go To Definition" fails if I reference a ts file, even though if I instead reference links.js, which is identical, it works.  Of course, if I reference links.js, then it opens the JavaScript editor, and if I then right-click within the file and go to definitions, it takes me to the *.js files, not to the *.ts files, which is what I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you get this feature if you install resharper, I might be wrong though.

Comment: With Resharper 8.1, it's closer.  Right-clicking within JavaScript files and going to the declaration actually goes to Typescript.  The Go To Definition context menu option goes away when editing html files.  But the Peek Definition option becomes more functional.  It takes you to the JavaScript definition, and from there you can right click and get to the Typescript.  You can do this from JavaScript inside script tags, but not from DOM events, like onclick.  Closer, but not quite as convenient as WebStorm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd definitely suggest the ReSharper.

Press Alt + 7 and a get list of useful navigation shortcuts (Navigate to...):

- F12 - Declaration (when you want to "jump into" declaration from usage),

  - You can also do Ctrl + Click
- Shift + F12 - Find usages
- Alt + F12 (this one is not in list but it opens Declaration in the context - to quick overview)

So, the answer: **Yes, press F12**.